# New fridge, fridge is warm, freezer is working fine

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

I just bought a new fridge, GE bottom freezer. I had to disassemble it to get it in the kitchen, in 1952 no appliance must have had a dimension greater then 31 inches, So I'm really not in the mood to start the fiasco again.

The freezer works, making ice and the ice is staying frozen. The fridge on the other hand doesn't. When you plug it in, the lights come on and it seems like it's working, but after 10 minutes the light(LED) doesn't come on and the fridge is a balmy 70F hours later. freezer is still at zero F.

It's under warranty, but I'm really not trying to have 2 fridges in a really cramped(11x11) kitchen any longer than I have too. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly did you disassemble? Did you tilt it or lay it on its front, back side when bringing it up or in?  Did you leave it sit 24 hours before spinning it up?

Comment: The freezer compartment of most modern refrigerators is the only part that has the coils that remove the heat. Heat is removed from the fridge section via adjustable openings between the two, sometimes assisted by a fan. It is not uncommon (under certain conditions) for the openings to become iced over, preventing adequate heat removal from the fridge. Look for these openings and ensure they are open and ice free.

Comment: I had to remove the doors, shelves, brackets included. It's more of a pain in the rump then it sounds.  Fridge was never layed down,  sat for 12+hours before being reassembled and turned on.

Jimmy, being that the fridge has never been run to my knowledge, I doubt ICE is an issue, if it is then that's a bad ass freezer.

Comment: It helps if you provide a model number for your fridge.

Comment: Model-GNE25JSKCFSS
There is a tiny bit of air moving, like can't move paper but it's there. I'm sure it's the control board adding the lights stop working after 3-5 minutes.

Comment: The manual says it was shipped with a protective film on the temperature sensor. Did you remove it?

Comment: Actually, it was a faulty door sensor. the computer would see the doors staying open and kill the fan. Not how I'd do it, but I didn't design the thing...

Comment: _"it was a faulty door sensor"_ -- you should post that as an answer and accept it, to avoid the question continuing to clutter up the web site as it it were still in need of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a faulty door sensor. the computer would see the doors staying open and kill the fan. Not how I'd do it, but I didn't design the thing... –

Answer (score 0):

You might have a loose connection in one of the plugs or the fan isn't blowing or there might be styrofoam stuck in the vent.you might have to take the panel off of the inside to check.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure there aren't any air holes between the fridge and freezer that are blocked. Some cheaper fridges have them and they can sometimes get blocked by food or even ice dams caused by defrost cycles not draining properly.

Answer (score 0):

The fridge temp adjust just opens a vent between freezer to fridge (on most, some expensive have 2 compressors) adjust that knob feel the air flow at vent should be noticiably stranger.  If no difference,  but some flow your knob/wheel was bumpedal loose from the vent.  Interior disassembly necessary to relink

Answer (score -1):

OK I’ve been doing this for a long time locate the low side of the compressor install a piercing Schrader valve
At this point you are ready to take your Freon that you bought from the auto parts store and put it onto a Schrader cap
You may need an adapter
Hi, normally overcharge the system of course purging the air out of the tube of the canned that I purchased then I start the compressor. I use a tire gauge on my Schrader valve and I get it just below 10 pounds of pressure as it’s running. That’s all you need if that doesn’t work throw the damn thing out. You only do this at last resort especially after you have tested your thermos there as your freezer gets cold and then a little door opens up to allow your refrigerator to get cold. That little door is not opening up with your thermistor the only thing gonna get cold is your freezer old ones have a mechanics thermistor the new ones Dave snuck it into the circuit board

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, is hard to read, and the question has already been answered by the original poster with what the problem was - a door switch.  Nothing to do with refrigerant.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).